# Disable Mail.app "special" text replacements (i.e., ... –> …) that are not present in global settings

Tags: macos, mail.app, bug, preferences, text-input

Most notably my Mail.app and Notes.app perform text replacements of `...`. to `…`, which I do not want.

I do have text replacements globally enabled and want to keep it that way, but I have deleted a previously existing replacement rule of these ellipses a while ago and rebooted since then. Elsewhere this replacement does also no occur, e.g., while the specified replacements work fine in this input here, the ellipses replacement does – also correctly – not happen.

How can I convince Mail.app (and Notes.app) to not perform this substitution?

This is on Catalina (10.15.4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to get the behavior you want by disabling **Edit > Substitutions > Smart Dashes** per app.  It appears ellipses are grouped with dashes.

If you want to use N and M dashes, they can be typed with **⌥-** and **⌥⌘-** , respectively.

[image: image of described menu command]

Comment: Thanks, that works. Typical Apple:-(putting ellipses into dashes is not outrageous, but it did not occur to me beforehand:-)

Comment: The other _interesting_ point (question) is why there is actually a set of global settings (on the side of System Preferences –> Keyboard –> Text) and then the in-app settings, seemingly overriding system settings.

Comment: Presumably the reasoning is just that:  to be able to override the system settings per app.  For example, I want smart quotes in any app I use to write, but none of the ones I use to code.